# How to make https post request in Cakephp

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, post, https

I have requirement where app has to make REST API calls over HTTPS POST. I am new to cakephp. I was thinking if I could do https calls using httpsocket.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have PHP's Curl module enabled:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('Your' => 'Data');

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result); // output result for all the kings
?>
```

Comment: you can simplify your code using HttpSocket, its good to take advantage of cakephp

Comment: HttpSocket is a bit bloated for simple tasks.

Comment: @RobinDuckett making a blanket statement that it's bloated is not useful. There is no way to tell if you are biased, repeating something you heard, or are making a legitimate claim. Will you please elaborate? Why and what makes HttpSocket bloated compared to other options?

Answer (score 26):

You can use any of these

`CAKEPHP SOCKET`

```
// Use either of the following two:
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket'); // Cake 1.x
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'); // Cake 2.x

$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$results = $HttpSocket->post('www.somesite.com/add', array('name' => 'test', 'type' => 'user'));  
//$results contains what is returned from the post.
```

`CURL`

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = 'var1=value1&var2=value2';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`JAVASCRIPT` if you want this to done at client side

Answer (score 3):

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
```

did not work for me on Cake 2.x, but

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

did work. Here's more about HttpSocket http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html