# Cakephp send parameters to another url from controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x. I want to send data to another url from controller so I can access the data from their.

I want to do something like this :

```
function senddata(){
   $a = 1;
   $b= hello;
   http://anotherwebsite/$a
}
```

I want to POST these values to another url. So I can get the values like this

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
```

How can I send data to external url from controller ?

Comment: you need to do this with curl, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254645/how-to-make-https-post-request-in-cakephp

Comment: Thats wrong, CakePHP has the HttpSocket class for that.

Comment: @burzum well i have used the socket class but i am not able to access the variables on my other url .. i mean the url which i have written in http socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i found the solution .. i have done this in order to accomplish this

```
 App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();


$results = $HttpSocket->post(
    'http://example.com/add',
    'name=test&type=user'
);
```

source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html